# Electron-webpack with Angular - Import styles with view encapsulation

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader

I'm using **electron-webpack** with my Angular app, based on this example:

https://github.com/kendraio/angular-electron-webpack-example

Just about every example I can find imports styles in a way that breaks view encapsulation of the styles.

The standard Angular way to import styles is through component styleUrls:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
```

The way I see it done (and how I've been doing it for lack of a better way), is

```
import "./app.component.scss";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

I've tried various configurations for loaders to no avail. Does anyone have an example of their webpack.renderer.additions.js that allows Angular styles to be imported the way they were intended?

**Note:**
In addition to component styles at `src/renderer/app/components/**/*.scss`, I also have some global `styles at src/renderer/styles/*.scss`

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this isn't possible.
Its because Angular appends the component class name to all of styles in `styleUrls`.

3rd party libraries have no way to know the component class name.